# Google charts not displaying on browser

Tags: javascript

Below is the code I have for displaying the Chart . I am unsure as to what is going wrong here.

Please bear with me , this is the first time I have asked a question in this forum.

Thank you for your help

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(DrawChart);
  function DrawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Short Shipment', 'Product Questions', 'Product Service Request', 'Billing Question','Product Issue','Return or Exchange Request','- None -'],
      [1, 3, 4, 8, 8, 11, 283]]);


    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Case Issue Summary'

      },
      bars: 'horizontal' 
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('BarChartCase'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body padding="0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in" size="Letter">
<div id="BarChartCase" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">&nbsp;</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is 99/100 copied from [developers.google.com/chart/....](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#creating-material-bar-charts)

The only changes you made is the `width` and `height` to 200 and 100.

Change it to a greater number and you'll be able to see your bar chart.

[codepen copy](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MejXgX)

Comment: Hi Nick , I increased the width and height , I still do not see the chart on Chrome or IE8 or Firefox. Is there any other reason , the chart does not show because as you pointed out it is a copy of the sample code . Testing this one out before I write custom code to integrate charts into NetSuite

Comment: @Bharath There's a big warning text on the website: `Note: Material Charts will not work in old versions of Internet Explorer. (IE8 and earlier versions don't support SVG, which Material Charts require.)`